# using Jquery to cause asp:FileUpload to choose filese

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I want to use jquery/javascript to make a FileUpload control "Choose" the files it wants to upload, without prompting the user. I mean, skip the user browsing screen, i'll supply it with the path for the file.
Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/05/9990371.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, this will *never* be possible.

You're asking for full read access to the user's entire hard disk.

Comment: What's the difference between this and a drag and drop file upload? when you drag and drop don't you only get the path anyway?

Comment: @Guy: When using drag & drop, you can only get a file if the **user** gives it to you.  You're asking to be able to read an arbitrary path on disk (such as `/etc/passwd`) with a hidden auto-submitting form.

Comment: lets assume I got the user's files paths from him. can I, after getting the paths from him, upload it? or when he gives them (By drag and drop) i actually get the files and not their paths?

Comment: @Guy are you just trolling for fun? Do you really understand the implications of what you're suggesting?

Comment: I do. and I'm not trolling for fun. I'm developing a webapp, and wanted to allow the user some functionality that now I understand is potentially harmful. thx.